# SASS stops compiling: File to import not found or unreadable: util/util

Tags: laravel-5, sass, gulp, zurb-foundation, gulp-sass

I have started a Laravel 5.3 project with Zurb Foundation (sass) a while ago. I configured gulpfile.js to compile my sass and **it used to work** properly until today where it stopped compiling. **It worked a couple days ago**.
I did not touch the code or upgrade anything in between...

Error:

```
MBP-Nicolas:v1 nicolas$ gulp
[15:50:09] Using gulpfile ~/Documents/Developpement/PHP/Laravel/Project/v1/gulpfile.js
[15:50:09] Starting 'default'...
[15:50:09] Starting 'sass'...

Fetching Sass Source Files...
   - resources/assets/sass/app.scss


Saving To...
   - public/css/app.css

[15:50:11] Finished 'default' after 1.31 s
[15:50:11] gulp-notify: [Laravel Elixir] Sass Compilation Failed: resources/assets/sass/_settings.scss
Error: File to import not found or unreadable: util/util
       Parent style sheet: /Users/nicolas/Documents/Developpement/PHP/Laravel/Project/v1/resources/assets/sass/_settings.scss
        on line 43 of resources/assets/sass/_settings.scss
>> @import 'util/util';
   ^

{ [Error: resources/assets/sass/_settings.scss
Error: File to import not found or unreadable: util/util
       Parent style sheet: /Users/nicolas/Documents/Developpement/PHP/Laravel/Project/v1/resources/assets/sass/_settings.scss
        on line 43 of resources/assets/sass/_settings.scss
>> @import 'util/util';
   ^
]
  status: 1,
  file: '/Users/nicolas/Documents/Developpement/PHP/Laravel/Project/v1/resources/assets/sass/_settings.scss',
  line: 43,
  column: 1,
  message: 'resources/assets/sass/_settings.scss\nError: File to import not found or unreadable: util/util\n       Parent style sheet: /Users/nicolas/Documents/Developpement/PHP/Laravel/Project/v1/resources/assets/sass/_settings.scss\n        on line 43 of resources/assets/sass/_settings.scss\n>> @import \'util/util\';\n   ^\n',
  formatted: 'Error: File to import not found or unreadable: util/util\n       Parent style sheet: /Users/nicolas/Documents/Developpement/PHP/Laravel/Project/v1/resources/assets/sass/_settings.scss\n        on line 43 of resources/assets/sass/_settings.scss\n>> @import \'util/util\';\n   ^\n',
  messageFormatted: '\u001b[4mresources/assets/sass/_settings.scss\u001b[24m\nError: File to import not found or unreadable: util/util\n       Parent style sheet: /Users/nicolas/Documents/Developpement/PHP/Laravel/Project/v1/resources/assets/sass/_settings.scss\n        on line 43 of resources/assets/sass/_settings.scss\n>> @import \'util/util\';\n   ^\n',
  messageOriginal: 'File to import not found or unreadable: util/util\nParent style sheet: /Users/nicolas/Documents/Developpement/PHP/Laravel/Project/v1/resources/assets/sass/_settings.scss',
  relativePath: 'resources/assets/sass/_settings.scss',
  name: 'Error',
  stack: 'Error: resources/assets/sass/_settings.scss\nError: File to import not found or unreadable: util/util\n       Parent style sheet: /Users/nicolas/Documents/Developpement/PHP/Laravel/Project/v1/resources/assets/sass/_settings.scss\n        on line 43 of resources/assets/sass/_settings.scss\n>> @import \'util/util\';\n   ^\n\n    at options.error (/Users/nicolas/Documents/Developpement/PHP/Laravel/Project/v1/node_modules/node-sass/lib/index.js:292:26)',
  showStack: false,
  showProperties: true,
  plugin: 'gulp-sass' }
[15:50:11] Finished 'sass' after 1.38 s
[15:50:11] Starting 'copy'...

Fetching Copy Source Files...
   - node_modules/font-awesome/fonts/**/*


Saving To...
   - public/fonts

[15:50:11] Finished 'copy' after 55 ms
[15:50:11] Starting 'styles'...

Fetching Styles Source Files...
   - node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css
   - public/css/app.css


Saving To...
   - public/css/all.css

[15:50:11] gulp-notify: [Laravel Elixir] Stylesheets Merged!
[15:50:11] Finished 'styles' after 95 ms
[15:50:11] Starting 'scripts'...

Fetching Scripts Source Files...
   - node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js
   - node_modules/foundation-sites/dist/foundation.min.js
   - resources/assets/js/main.js


Saving To...
   - public/js/all.js

[15:50:12] gulp-notify: [Laravel Elixir] Scripts Merged!
[15:50:12] Finished 'scripts' after 1.3 s
```

I don't really know what else you need but here is my gulpfile:

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

elixir(function(mix) {

    //Compilation SASS
    mix.sass('app.scss', null, null, { includePaths: ['node_modules/foundation-sites/scss'] });

    //Copy of fonts
    mix.copy('node_modules/font-awesome/fonts', 'public/fonts');

    //Compilation CSS
    mix.styles([
        '../../../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css',
        '../../../public/css/app.css'
    ]);

    //Compilation JavaScript
    var JSJquery = '../../../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js';
    var JSFoundation = '../../../node_modules/foundation-sites/dist/foundation.min.js';

    mix.scripts([
        JSJquery,
        /*JSFoundation + 'foundation.core.js',
         JSFoundation + 'foundation.util.keyboard.js',
         JSFoundation + 'foundation.util.box.js',
         JSFoundation + 'foundation.util.triggers.js',
         JSFoundation + 'foundation.util.mediaQuery.js',
         JSFoundation + 'foundation.util.motion.js',
         JSFoundation + 'foundation.reveal.js',
         JSFoundation + 'foundation.offcanvas.js',*/
        JSFoundation,
        'main.js'
    ]);

});
```

Line 43 of _settings.scss is `@import 'util/util';`.
If it is useful, some versions of the tools:

1. node -v: v4.6.0
2. npm -v: 2.15.9
3. sass -v: Sass 3.4.15 (Selective
   Steve)

But like I said, I don't recall upgrading any of it.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your gulp file and sass file you should have your util.scss file at location 'node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/util/util.scss' This is because you have the following in your gulp file

```
mix.sass('app.scss', null, null, { includePaths: ['node_modules/foundation-sites/scss'] });
```

and the following in your settings file

```
util/util
```

Ensure the file is at that location, if not, modify your gulpfile or settings file accordingly.

Edit: Can you post your 'sass' task from your gulpfile, this might help?

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply. The location of the file is correct, see the image: http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/784570util.png

Comment: What does 'sass task' mean?

Comment: In your gulpfile.js you should have a gulp task named sass. Something like this... `gulp.task('sass', function() { ... });` . If you paste the content it will help troubleshoot.

Comment: What I pasted in the first post is all I got written in my gulpfile.js, nothing more...

Comment: I see, this seems like an issue that is specific to elixir, which unfortunately I don't have experience with.

Comment: Thanks for your help even if you couldn't find the solution. I hope someone else will be able to help.

Comment: It works by writing the full path to the node_modules. Weird it happens now though.